# BackgroundWorker to display the process % along with a string

Tags: c#

I've a background worker that calling a recursive subroutine that traverse a directory, subdirectory and populate the file names into an array.  I've a backgroundworker process that is doing this and this also return the percent.  I also have a public string dirName that contain the current directory at any given moment and I want it to display together with the percentage (e.g. Processing dirName....nn%), how do I do that?

```
void m_bgWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox1.Visible = true;
    pictureBox1.Refresh();

    progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;

    lblStatus.Text = "Processing + dirName + "....." + progressBar1.Value.ToString() + "%";
}

void m_bgWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    if (m_bgWorker.CancellationPending)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        m_bgWorker.ReportProgress(0);
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        //e.Result containing an array of directories
        e.Result = processFile(pgmName, pgmPath, worker, e);
    }

    m_bgWorker.ReportProgress(100);
}
```

Comment: You'd have to do a two step process and count the number of sub directories and files from your root first and then run over them again doing the work before you can properly do any %.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `processFile()` method, you'd report progress and pass back the directory using the overload of [`ReportProgress()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3zbdb1t%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that takes an object:

```
int progress = 0;
string directory = "C:\Foo\Bazz";
while(...)
{
    //...
    //...
    m_bgWorker.ReportProgress(progress, directory);
}
```

Then in your `m_bgWorker_ProgressChanged()`, you'd do this to get the directory out:

```
void m_bgWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
   pictureBox1.Visible = true;
   pictureBox1.Refresh();

   progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
   string dirName = e.UserState.ToString();

   lblStatus.Text = "Processing" + dirName + "....." + progressBar1.Value.ToString() + "%";
}
```

A great resource for learning more about BackgroundWorker is Joseph Albahari's [page](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part3.aspx#_BackgroundWorker) on the class, which is a part of a larger article on threading in C#.

Comment: Thanks ledbutter but I got an error saying System.ComponentModel.ProcessChangedEvenArgs does not contain a definition for 'Objectstate'.

Comment: Sorry, it is `UserState`, not `ObjectState`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @user1387287 you are welcome, would you mind marking this as the answer then?